# Таймер на Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Помогите, пожалуйста.
Пишу бота, есть команда, после ввода которой через 30 секунд должно выполняться действие, помогите написать таймер на Node JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bot.on('название события', function (message) {
  setTimeout(function(){ dejstvie; }, 30000);
});
```

Comment: нужно какие-то библиотеки подключать?

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев нет, не нужно

Comment: у меня setTimeot серым выделено

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев если у вас и в коде опечатка, то это и неудивительно. Но если нет, значит ваш инструмент разработки слишком глупенький, см. документацию: [Because the timer functions are globals, there is no need to call `require('timers')` to use the API.](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setinterval_callback_delay_args)

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев `setTimeot` != `setTimeout`

Comment: я понял, я же бота делаю, и там команды добавляются в виде 
bot.on(команда), function (message, {users}) {действия} И чтобы например в действии взаимодействовать с командой message.send написать message, я пытался написать там setTimeout но это не помогло

Comment: Не в опечатке дело!

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев - как Вы "пытался написать там setTimeout"?

Comment: ну написал, зачем к словам придираться?

Comment: function (message, {setTimeout, users})

Comment: Взаимодействовать с message нужно внутри функции внутри setTimeout, там где в примере написано "dejstvie;".